# Get sub messages from Outlook .msg files

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to parse a few .msg files which have trail mails. Is there any way to get the sub messages and identify the initiated and the responded emails.
I do not want to use any third party tools. I am allowed to use the Outlook interop.
Below is the code that I have used to read the msg file.I am able to get the Body ,HTMLBody and other details.But I actually need all the trailing messages.

```
    outlook._Application app = null;
    outlook.MailItem item = null;
    outlook.NameSpace session = null;
    try
    {
        app = new outlook.Application();
        session = app.Session;
        item = session.OpenSharedItem(file) as outlook.MailItem;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to OOM only, the only way to do that is to save each embedded message attachment as an MSG file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), then open it using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, an MSG file can be opened using [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` (similar to `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` in OOM), and the embedded message attachment can be accessed using the [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).EmbeddedMsg property (returns [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object) - no need to save the attachment first.

Comment: Here the submessages are not the ones in the attachement but the actual trail emails that are present in the msg File

Comment: Saving MSG attachments (whether they are embedded messages or by-value attachments) would work in both cases.